# Java enum constant value won't change

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, constants

So this isn't one of those "I want to change a constant value during runtime, why is it not working?" questions, just as a heads-up. I'm having trouble changing a Java Enum's value in code. I've made the change, saved, and re-run my program, but the value in-code has remained with the old value. I'm using the Enum.values() method to cycle through my Enum constants and the value is showing as the old value, not the new value I've directly typed into the enum. I'm starting to wonder if I'm losing my mind or my program has decided not to recompile my Enum or what. A sanity check would be welcome. See below for the entirety of my enum's code and where I am accessing the values.

```
public enum MSSQLType implements DBType {
//String Types
CHAR(8000, -1, null, "CHAR","TEXT"),
VARCHAR(8000, -1, null, "VARCHAR", "TEXT"),
TEXT(-1, -1, null, "TEXT", "TEXT"),
NCHAR(4000, -1, null, "CHAR", "TEXT"),
NVARCHAR(4000, -1, null, "VARCHAR", "TEXT"),
NTEXT(-1, -1, null, "TEXT", "TEXT"),
//Numeric Types
BIGINT(19, -1, null, "BIGINT", "BIGINT"),
BIGINT_IDENTITY (19, -1, null, null, null),
INT(10, -1, null, "INT", "BIGINT"),
SMALLINT(5, -1, null, "SMALLINT", "BIGINT"),
TINYINT(3, -1, null, "TINYINT", "BIGINT"),
BIT(1, -1, null, "TINYINT", "BIGINT"),
DECIMAL(14, 38, null, "DECIMAL", "DECIMAL"),
NUMERIC(14, 38, null, "DECIMAL", "DECIMAL"),
MONEY(15, 4, null, "DECIMAL", "DECIMAL"),
SMALLMONEY(6,4, null, "DECIMAL", "DECIMAL"),
FLOAT(-1, 53, null, "FLOAT", "FLOAT"),
REAL(-1, 106, null, "FLOAT", "FLOAT"),
//Date/time types
DATETIME(-1, -1, "YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS", "DATETIME", "DATETIME"),
SMALLDATETIME(-1, -1, "YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS", "DATETIME", "DATETIME"),
//Other types
BINARY(-1,-1, null, null, null),
VARBINARY(-1,-1, null, null, null),
IMAGE(-1,-1, null, null, null),
CURSOR(-1,-1, null, null, null),
SQL_VARIANT(-1,-1, null, null, null),
TABLE(-1,-1, null, null, null),
TIMESTAMP(-1, -1, "YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS", "DATETIME", "DATETIME"),
UNIQUEIDENTIFIER(-1, -1, null, null, null);

private int size;
private int precision;
private String format;
private String convertTo;
private String fallback;

MSSQLType(int size, int precision, String format, String convertTo, String fallback) {
    this.size = size;
    this.precision = precision;
    this.format = format;
    this.convertTo = convertTo;
    this.fallback = fallback;
}
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public int getPrecision() {
    return precision;
}

public String getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public String getConvertTo() {
    return convertTo;
}

public String getFallback() {
    return fallback;
}

@Override
public String getDisplay() {
    return toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString().replaceAll("_", " ");
}
}
```

So the convertTo and fallback values of REAL were changed to "FLOAT", "FLOAT" from "DOUBLE", "DOUBLE", but the code is still assigning the constant String "DOUBLE" to those two values! The values are being read out as so:

```
for (MSSQLType msSqlType : MSSQLType.values()) {
            if (typeName.equalsIgnoreCase(msSqlType.toString())) {
                this.type = msSqlType;
                return;
            }
        }
```

I've also tried using MSSQLType.class.getEnumConstants() with the same result.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to "clean and build" your project (not sure how it's called in eclipse)?

Comment: Looks like a binary version mismatch in your class files (enums are not compiled in clients though...)

Comment: Yes, was pretty much my first port of call. Even tried deleting the existing ".class" files and re-building.

Comment: Just tried commenting out REAL, and my own "Type not found" exception is thrown as I'd expect. I'm really at a loss.

Comment: Guess you've also already tried copying relevant classes to a new project?

Comment: No, though I can't see how that would help. Then again, I can't see how there would be a problem to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `msSqlType.toString()` method you should use `msSqlType.name()` method.
Default `toString()` method on `enum` returns `name` but not if you have overridden it in `DBType` class.

```
 if (typeName.equalsIgnoreCase(msSqlType.name())) {
            this.type = msSqlType;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the issue. I am overriding toString() as part of my implementation, but this is all it does:
    `@Override  
 public String toString() {  
  return super.toString().replaceAll("_", " ");  
 }`  

And I have confirmed that it is returning the correct String in that line of code (which in this case, is "REAL").